# Read Avro with Spark in java

Tags: java, apache-spark, avro

Can somebody share example of reading avro using java in spark?
Found scala examples but no luck with java.
Here is the code snippet which is part of code but running into compilation issues with the method  `ctx.newAPIHadoopFile`.

```
JavaSparkContext ctx = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
Configuration hadoopConf = new Configuration();
JavaRDD<SampleAvro> lines = ctx.newAPIHadoopFile(path, AvroInputFormat.class, AvroKey.class, NullWritable.class, new Configuration());
```

Regards

Comment: Could you please share more information about the compilation issues you are running into?  Errors, stack trace, etc.

Comment: Its giving compilation error saying that expected java.lang.class<F> actual is AvroInputFormat.class and the same for rest of the arguments except path,hadoopConf . Any help where i am getting wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use the *spark-avro connector library* by Databricks.
The recommended way to read or write Avro data from Spark SQL is by using Spark's DataFrame APIs.

The connector enables both reading and writing Avro data from Spark SQL:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.*;

SQLContext sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc);

// Creates a DataFrame from a specified file
DataFrame df = sqlContext.read().format("com.databricks.spark.avro")
    .load("src/test/resources/episodes.avro");

// Saves the subset of the Avro records read in
df.filter($"age > 5").write()
    .format("com.databricks.spark.avro")
    .save("/tmp/output");
```

Note that this connector has **different** versions for Spark 1.2, 1.3, and 1.4+:

<kbd>Spark ver</kbd><kbd>connector</kbd>
<kbd>1.2</kbd>         
<kbd>0.2.0</kbd>      
<kbd>1.3</kbd>         
<kbd>1.0.0</kbd>      
<kbd>1.4+</kbd>       
<kbd>2.0.1</kbd>

Using Maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.databricks</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-avro_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>{AVRO_CONNECTOR_VERSION}</version>
</dependency>
```

See further info at: [Spark SQL Avro Library](https://github.com/databricks/spark-avro)

Comment: Any idea how one might do it via the Hadoop InputFormat API, in Java?

Comment: @Jordan - Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5480308/getting-started-with-avro

Comment: @Jordan - And I think this: https://github.com/apache/avro/tree/trunk/lang/java/mapred/src/main/java/org/apache/avro/mapreduce

Comment: @leet_Falcon, Thanks, I have already tried Spark SQL with Avro but no luck so far. The below error message what i am getting Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.read()Lorg/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameReader;
 at org.opencb.hpg.bigdata.tools.sparkanalytics.SaprkSQLAvro.main(SaprkSQLAvro.java:19).

Comment: @kre - Do you use Spark 1.4+ ?

Comment: @Leet-Falcon yes. this is my pom file   <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.databricks</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-avro_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: @kre - Spark-core & spark-sql should have the same version. spark-avro is ok

Answer (score 1):

Here, assuming K is your Key and V is your value:

```
....

val job = new Job();

job.setInputFormatClass(AvroKeyValueInputFormat<K, V>.class);

FileInputFormat.addInputPaths(job, <inputPaths>);
AvroJob.setInputKeySchema(job, <keySchema>);
AvroJob.setInputValueSchema(job, <valueSchema>);

RDD<AvroKey<K>, AvroValue<V>> avroRDD = 
  sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(job.getConfiguration,
  AvroKeyValueInputFormat<<K>, <V>>,
  AvroKey<K>.class,
  AvroValue<V>.class);
```